# Intermediate Value for Connected Subset of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

> Show that a path going from one vertex of the unit square (in $\mathbb{C}$) to its opposite and a second path going between the other pair of opposite vertices must intersect. By path I mean continuous function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ with $f(0)$ one vertex and $f(1)$ the other. [EDIT] Both are paths **in the unit square** (no going outside)

I looked through other questions and didn't quite find an answer to this. I know that the intermediate value theorem says that $\textrm{Im}((f-g)(t))$ and $\textrm{Re}((f-g)(t))$ must be $0$ at some point, but I'm not sure how to show that this must occur at the same point.

Comment: I assume both paths must stay in the unit square ?

Comment: Both paths must stay in the unit square

Comment: Duplicate of [Why do “path diagonals” of a rectangle need to intersect?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937510/why-do-path-diagonals-of-a-rectangle-need-to-intersect/) ?

Comment: ^Oh, did not see this. This is a duplicate.

Comment: Wait this is not a duplicate really because that post appealed to more advanced machinery than I am looking for in its solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that such paths exist, for a contradiction. Let $S$ be the unit square, and $I(f),I(g)$ be the images of the paths. Let $v_{1},v_{2}$ be the vertices of $S$ which are end-points of $I(f)$. Note that $v_{1},v_{2} \notin I(g)$, since $I(g) \cap I(f)$ is empty.

One can proceed by showing that $v_{1},v_{2}$ lie in different connected components of $S \setminus I(g)$ by applying the intermediate value theorem "along the diagonal". Then one gets a contradiction since the existence of the path $f$ shows that these connected components are the same.

Comment: That's surely the right idea but there's no intermediate value theorem in $\Bbb C $ as shown by $f (t)=e^{it} $

Comment: I mean apply intermediate value theorem to the real function D(x+iy) = x+y.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't see how this shows that $v_{1}$ and $v_{3}$ are in different connected components.